# Save column of datagridview in List<string>

Tags: c#, list

I have datagridview that contain of two columns (id, name). Now I need to add the value of column name to `List<string>`

```
 List<string> name = new List<string>();
 for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
 {
     string w = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
     name.Add(w);
 }
```

When I try to run the project, the following error that appear.

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

How can I fix my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's better if you use a foreach..

Something like this:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow i in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
   if(i.Cells[1].Value != null){
       name.Add(i.Cells[1].Value.ToString());        
    }
   
}
```

Comment: I have edited my code. That error, probably you are trying add null values to a list... This will verify the null values and will not implement them. Give some feedback after try.

Comment: @AfraArif Glad to know!